# Post jQuery ajax form the same way as normal html form, breaking same-origin-policy

Tags: jquery, ajax, same-origin-policy

I have written a jQuery solution for submitting a form to a third party domain. The third party url accepts forms posted from other domains when the form is posted with normal html. I cannot make this happen with jQuery and $.post.

Example:
sender url: http...domain1
receiver url: https...domain2

When I submit the form on domain1.com using normal html everything works fine. The problem is when I use $.post() jQuery throws an error as soon as the target domain is using https. Ie8 throws an error already when receiver url is http...domain2.

My question is how I can use jQuery and submit the form the same way as normal html does. I'd like the solution to work in ie8 as well preferrably. Also, I'd prefer not to use Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * (set as a header in php on the target server). Is there a way to use jQuery, and send ajax forms with the same result as a normal html form?

```
<html lang='sv'>
<head>
    <script src='js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js'></script>
    <script>
    $(function()
    {
        $.post(
            // works in all browsers but ie8 with Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
            "http...domain2/?ts="+new Date().getMilliseconds(),
            // breaks in chrome, didn't test others
            //"https...domain2/?ts="+new Date().getMilliseconds(),
            { a:"a", b:"b" },
            function(responseText)
            {
                alert(responseText);
            },
            "json"  
            //"html" // seems to get same result as when using "json" above
        ).done(function(){
            alert("done!");
        }).error(function(event){
            alert("error!");
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
 <!-- working form -->
 <form action="https...domain2/?ts=whatever" method="post">
  <textarea name="a">a</textarea>
  <textarea name="b">b</textarea>
  <input type="submit">
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if we can BREAK same origin policy. But we can still make thins to work (Using proxies and by tweaking same origin policy).
You can use a PHP proxy on same domain to make cross domain call (As browsers like mozilla will not allow you to make cross domain call). Forward each reueest to proxy and make cross domain call through proxy.

[image]

For more details with sample PHP proxy http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however PHP was not an option in this case. I didn't understand why ajax would not be allowed to have the same privileges as html-post. Either way, I went with the plain html solution.